# Словотвірні ланцюжки від "стигма" та "стигмат"

Tags: вибір-слова, синоніми, словотворення, морфологія

Зіткнувшись з терміном **`соціальна стигматизація`**, виявила, що іменник **`стигматизація`** походить від грецького **`стигма`**.

> **[Соціальна стигматизація](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F)** (грец. Στíγμα — тавро, клеймо) — негативне виділення суспільством індивіда (або соціальної групи) за
>   якоюсь ознакою з відповідним стереотипним набором соціальних реакцій
>   на цього індивіда (або представників соціальної групи). На
>   стигматизацію впливають забобони, ідеологеми, які історично
>   встановилися у конкретному суспільстві і стали частиною їхнього
>   світогляду. При цьому певні характеристики індивіда не беруться до
>   уваги.

Як свідчить українська вікіпедія, термін [**`стигма`**](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%B0) має кілька значень в різних галузях - у біології, медицині, історії.

СУМ тлумачить так:

> [**СТИ́ГМА**](http://sum.in.ua/s/styghma), и, жін.
>
> 1. іст. У стародавній Греції — клеймо на тілі раба або злочинця.
> 2. мед. Кривава виразка або червона пляма на тілі людини;  //  Загальна назва різних шкіряних захворювань, викликаних істерією.
> 3. зоол. У павукоподібних, багатоніжок і комах — отвір, яким відкриваються назовні органи дихання; дихальце. Дорослі комахи
>      звичайно дихають за допомогою трахей, які починаються від дихалець
>      (стигм), що розташовані на сегментах тіла (Підручник дезинфекції,
>      1953, 168).
>
> Словник української мови: в 11 томах. — Том 9, 1978. — Стор. 693.,

а також пропонує ніби абсолютний синонім:

> [**СТИГМА́Т**](http://sum.in.ua/s/styghmat), а, чол., іст., мед. Те саме, що **стигма** 1, 2. До
>   своєрідних випадків істеричного самонавіювання належать, наприклад,
>   безсумнівні випадки уявної вагітності.. Сюди ж треба віднести стани і
>   стигмати різних релігійних екстатиків (Павлов, Фізіологія вищої
>   нервової діяльності, 1951, 157);  * Образно. Цілі покоління людські
>   трудилися над цим похмурим стигматом землі [Кельнським собором],
>   споруджували не радісний і світлий храм для своїх дітей, а понурий
>   пам'ятник для себе, для своїх сліз і своєї крові (Павло Загребельний,
>   Європа. Захід, 1961, 101).
>
> Словник української мови: в 11 томах. — Том 9, 1978. — Стор. 693.

Утім, українська вікі дає значно вужче тлумачення **`стигмату`**, до того ж у множині:

> [**Стигма́ти**](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8) (грец. στίγματος, «знаки, язви, рани») — тілесні
>   знаки, що з'являються на тілі живої особи і є схожими на п'ять ран (на
>   руках, ногах, і боці) котрі Христос отримав при розп'ятті. Понад 300
>   осіб стверджували про їх появу, особливо деякі глибокорелігійні.
>   Багато з них також стверджували про наявність у них дару ясновидіння.
>
> Стигмати є незнаними до 13 століття, Святий Франциск Ассизький був
>   першим святим, чий випадок був добре задокументований та визнаний
>   церковною владою. Висунено багато природніх пояснень, і
>   Римо-Католицька церква обережно ставиться до цього феномену, який не
>   складає основ для канонізації.
>
> У православній церкві це явище не є поширеним, до нього ставляться із
>   застереженням і тлумачать його у зв'язку з емоційними переживаннями.

**Якщо погодитись, що `стигма` й `стигмат` - поняття тотожні, а за словотворним ланцюжком однокореневий іменник, що відображає явище або процес, для обох з них - `стигматизація`, відтак дієслово - `стигматизувати`, то який із двох дієприкметників правильний (бо пошук Google видає результати для обох варіантів) - [`стигматизований`](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9&oq=%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.5819j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) чи [`стигмований`](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9&oq=%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9&aqs=chrome..69i57.3173j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)?**

**Якщо ж припустити, що словотвірні ланцюжки повинні відрізнятися, то має бути так:**

**`стигма`** - `стигмація, стигмувати, стигмований`,

**`стигмат`** - `стигматизація, стигматизувати, стигматизований`**?**

**Чи як інакше?**

Comment: А як вам така версія: слово "стигматизація" - запозичення, яке по формі співпадає із словом, що утворюється від неправильного "стигмату".

Comment: @Artemix, версія цікава. Але чому *стигмат* неправильний? Десь зустрічали таку думку? уккр вікі каже, що *стигма* - від дав.-гр. στίγμα, а *стигмат* - від грец. στίγματος, тобто *стигмат* ніби має право на існування.

Comment: Не в тому сенсі що він неправильний, а в тому що потрібний смисл у "стигми" - "клейма" а не у "стигмата" - "знака розп'яття". Обидва слова правильні :)

Comment: @Artemix, ну Сум не дуже розрізняє тлумачення, каже, що це - те ж саме, тобто потрібний смисл може бути і в стигмату. Тож мене і цікавить, чи словотвірні ланцюжки теж мають бути тотожні, чи різні. І в обох випадках (чи ланцюжок співпадає, чи ні), яке правильне дієслово і який правильний дієприкметник, бо зустрічаються варіанти і *стигматизований*, і *стигмований*.